# Curl авторизация

Tags: php, curl

Вообщем , нужна Curl авторизация на сайте zismo.

```
function request($url,$post = 0){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post!==0 ); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Накидал вот такую функцию, помогите к ней пределать логин и пароль, а также `auth_key`, который дается на странице `http://zismo.biz/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login`, вожусь уже целый день, не пойму как его оттуда спарсить.

Answer (score 0):

В начале дергаете страницу:

```
http://zismo.biz/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login
```

парсите на ней `value` поля `name='auth_key'` в форме `id='login'` (например в переменную `$auth_key`).

Пример *HTML* формы со страницы:

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="http://zismo.biz/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process">
    <input type="hidden" value="880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024" name="auth_key">
```

Исходя из примера выше, `$auth_key` должна содержать`'880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024'`

Далее отправляете `POST`, `URL` и `POST` поля, которые необходимо передать:

```
$url = 'http://zismo.biz/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process';
$post = array(
    'auth_key' => $auth_key // auth_key, который дернули ранее
    'ips_username' => 'username' // подставить логин
    'ips_password' => 'password' // подставить пароль
    'referer' => 'http://zismo.biz/'
    'rememberMe' => 1
);
```